# Using PowerMock to obtain the ATG Nucleus in testing results in NPE

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, atg

I am trying to test the following bit of code:

```
GSARepository productCatalog = (GSARepository) Nucleus.getGlobalNucleus().resolveName("/atg/commerce/catalog/ProductCatalog");
for (RepositoryItem orderItem : orderItems) {
    String product = (String) orderItem.getPropertyValue(PropertyNameConstants.PRODUCTID);
    if (!ProductUtils.isSpecial(product, productCatalog)) {
        isSpecial = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

clearly Nucleus.getGlobalNucleus() is static.

According to the docs I should be able to use:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Nucleus.class);
PowerMockito.when(Nucleus.getGlobalNucleus()).thenReturn(globalNucleusMock);    
PowerMockito.when(globalNucleusMock.resolveName("/atg/commerce/catalog/ProductCatalog");
```

Eitherway, I still get a nullpointer when I call:

```
Nucleus.getGlobalNucleus().resolveName("/atg/commerce/catalog/ProductCatalog")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to use JUnit runner :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Nucleus.class)
public class YourClassTest {
```

Comment: +1 for picking up that I missed @ PrepareForTest(Nucleus.class). I'm using TestNG as my testing framework so @ RunWith doesn't help me at the moment. I suspect I need to use @ ObjectFactory to generate my test runner. Missing some configs there so will sort that out next.

Comment: Found that I missed out the annotation:

    @PrepareForTest(Nucleus.class)

Also needed to create the ObjectFactory:

    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
     return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }

Comment: What is "globalNucleusMock" here? Have you declare it somewhere?

Comment: @Saurabh `globalNucleusMock` was defined as a class scoped variable using the annotation and syntax: `@Mock Nucleus globalNucleusMock`