# How to invoke GiftlistSiteFilterDroplet in Oracle ATG commerce?

Tags: java, atg, atg-dynamo, atg-droplet

I know how to invoke an ATG droplet from a jsp page. Below code snippet calls the GiftListSiteFilterDroplet.

```
 <dsp:droplet name="GiftlistSiteFilterDroplet">
    <dsp:param name="collection"  bean="/atg/userprofiling/Profile.giftlists"/>
     <dsp:oparam name="output">
      <dsp:getvalueof var="giftlists" param="filteredCollection" />
```

Above code will invoke the GiftlistSiteFilterDroplet. However, I'm trying to findout how to invoke the same droplet from a java class. There is a DropletInvoker class from ATG DUST. Example code is as below for calling Switch component.

```
Nucleus mNucleus = NucleusTestUtils.startNucleusWithModules(
new String[] {"DAS","DafEar"}, this.getClass(),"/atg/dynamo/droplet/Switch");
DropletInvoker invoker = new DropletInvoker(mNucleus);
DynamoHttpServletRequest request = invoker.getRequest();
DropletResult result = null;
request.setParameter("value", "foo");
result = invoker.invokeDroplet("/atg/dynamo/droplet/Switch");
```

However, GiftListSiteFilterDroplet has a bean parameter. I would like to know if we can pass this bean parameter using this DropletInvoker.

I would also like to know if there is anyway we can call droplet without using ATG DUST component. Is there any generic way of calling any droplet and pass the input parameters to it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? [ATG Dust](http://atgdust.sourceforge.net/) is a framework for building JUnit tests. Are you calling this for testing purposes or are you wanting to call the Droplet from another piece of code for a different reason?

Comment: It is for the purpose of testing. We are building a droplet of similar functionality, I'm trying to figure out various ways of testing this new component without creating jsp pages.

Comment: You can try using [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) instead of ATG Dust. There is an example of using this for a Droplet available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523741/using-mockito-for-writing-atg-test-case)

Comment: I agree with radimpe, Mockito is better than Dust, it is faster, more thoroughly TDD-oriented follow-up to EasyMock. You don't need to be running ATG modules to perform your tests.

Answer (score 1):

`atg.service.collections.filter.droplet.CollectionFilter`
is the class for the component `/atg/commerce/collections/filter/droplet/GiftlistSiteFilterDroplet`

Just invoke the `getFilter()` method in  the class

Refer:-
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/apidoc/atg/service/collections/filter/droplet/CollectionFilter.html

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGCommStoreGuide/html/s1712collectionfilter01.html

Thanks